# react.js line breaking up after removing css

Tags: reactjs

In my `React.js` application in one of my component's `render` function looks like this :

```
render() {
    return (
        <div >
                <form>
                <p>
                    <h1>
                        Error code : {this.state.errorCode}
                    </h1>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <h3>
                        Sorry! The request can not be processed.
                    </h3>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <button className="btn btn-sm btn-secondary btn-block btn-animated" onClick={this.GoBack}>
                        Go back
                    </button>
                </p>
                </form>
            </div>
    );
}
```

It renders correctly but the problem is :

It breaks up line into multiple lines.

Here is a snap :

[image: line break problem react.js]

Comment: well probably  from your css file, can you post your css!

Comment: This is how my `class` starts : `import React from 'react';  class Error extends React.Component { ...` no css..

Comment: Is it a child component and inheriting the css properties from the parent component?

Comment: No @PrabhatMishra , it's not inheriting... directly inheriting `React.Component`

Comment: well can you make a  codesandbox  of your code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those styling are getting inherited from some other Parent/Child Components or Css file.

I tried your code on codepen and it works fine. 
codepen.io/mohitpatil/pen/xxKzpgB

Seems like you are using bootstrap. If possible, check if your component is in some other component where container class is applied.